# Android Studio: Quitar botones en java sin perder el orden

Tags: java, android, android-studio

quisiera saber como quitar un botón en java, ejemplo con un

`setVisibility(View.GONE)`

pero que al mismo tiempo el botón que sigue se acomode al lado del otro, ocupando el lugar que este botón desocupó, y que los otros hagan lo mismo... tratare de expresarme en una imagen.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El boton rojo es el que eliminare con java, y luego quedaria la vista asi...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quisiera que se acomodaran de esta forma automáticamente...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hay alguna forma?

Comment: Agrega el código que usas para desaparecer el botón

Comment: no lo he echo, pero seria asi...

int disabled = 0;
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btnblablabla);

if(disabled == 0){
btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

Comment: GRacias a eso me refería, de hecho no había visto que indicas que usaste .setVisibility(View.GONE) he agregado respuesta, saludos.

Comment: Si usted quiere ocultar el botón y llenar su espacio. asi es: `btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si usas

[setVisibility(View.GONE);](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE)

La documentación menciona:

> Esta vista es invisible y no ocupa espacio para fines de diseño.

Pero si usas

[setVisibility(View.**INVISIBLE**);](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE)

> Esta vista es invisible, pero aún ocupa espacio para fines de diseño.

por lo tanto debes usar

```
   setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

para que la vista desaparezca pero que permanezca el espacio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En caso que desees cubrir el espacio vacío con un elemento y se re acomode automáticamente necesitarías un adapter que realice esta acción, pero como opción puedes usar la library **[Flexbox Layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí puedes encontrar un ejemplo de como implementar [**Flexbox layout en Android.**](https://www.dev2qa.com/android-flexbox-layout-example/)

Comment: si, pero quiero no llegar a este punto, lo puedo hacer asi pero quiero que se acomoden el resto, que el que quedo a la derecha ocupe el espacio en blanco, y los demas tambien se acomoden... osea que suba el primero de la ultima fila a la ultima posicion de la fila 3, que el 2do de la ultima fila pase al primero y asi... como dije en la 3ra imagen.

Comment: ¿Cómo podría lograr que se acomoden automáticamente, como lo muestra en la última imagen que se encuentra en la pregunta?

Comment: @Riaven usa https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: FlexBox ayuda mucho, gracias @Jorgesys

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solucion, implementando FlexBox que es una maravilla. Para integrarlo al android se agrega la dependencia:

```
implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'
```

y en nuestro xml, hacemos un FlexboxLayout

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:alignItems="center"
    app:alignContent="center"
    app:flexWrap="wrap">


    <!-- {{ Botones }} -->



</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

esto hará que los botones se adapten al width del layout y si no caben los manda hacia abajo, si algun boton llega a desaparecer, el otro tomara su lugar, aplicar setVisibility(View.GONE).

Espero les sea de ayuda.

Comment: "He encontrado la solucion", es lo que te sugerio Jorge en su respuesta

Comment: cierto, no me habia fijado. gracias a Jorgesys.